# Do I need a Canadian transit visa when I have a visitor visa?

Tags: visa, canada

I am a citizen of India and currently have a Canadian visitor visa that expires in 2018. I currently live in the US. My flight plan at the end of this year from US to India involves a layover in Canada for a couple of hours. Do I still need a transit visa or is my visitor visa enough?

Comment: Are you a permanent resident of the US (in other words, do you have a green card)?